# Base url doesn't change based on the link

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, es6-promise, query-string

I have a hardcoded JSON data that is displayed when the app is executed and I use JSON-schema-faker to get some mockApi data and display it when I set the query parameter useMockApi to true 
I want the link to change based on the environment but when I set useMockApi to true it gives me this error

```js
import { getUsers, deleteUser } from "./api/userApi.js";



getUsers().then(result => {
    let userBody = "";

    result.forEach(user => {
        userBody += `<tr>       
        <td><a href="#" id="${user.id}"  class="del">Delete </a></td>
        <td>${user.id}</td>
        <td>${user.firstName}</td>
        <td>${user.lastName}</td>
        <td>${user.email}</td>
        </tr>`
    });
    global.document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = userBody;

    const deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.del');

    Array.from(deleteLinks, link => {
        link.onclick = (event) => {
            const element = event.currentTarget;
            event.preventDefault();

            deleteUser(element.id) //eslint-disable-line no-console
            const row = element.parentNode.parentNode;
            row.remove();
        }
    })

})
```

Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from http://localhost:5000users

this is my code

```js
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import "whatwg-fetch";

import getBaseUrl from './baseUrl';

const baseurl = getBaseUrl();

export function getUsers() {
    return get('users');
}

export function deleteUser(id) {
    return del(`users/${id}`)
}

function get(url) {
    return fetch(baseurl + url).then(onSuccess, onError);
}

function del(url) {
    const request = new Request(`${baseurl}/${url}`, {
        method: 'DELETE'
    });
    return fetch(request).then(onSuccess, onError)

}

function onSuccess(response) {
    return response.json();
}

function onError(err) {
    console.log(err); //eslint-disable-line no-console
}
```

```js
export default function getBaseUrl() {
    return getQueryStringParameterByName('useMockApi') ? 'http://localhost:5000' : '/';
}


function getQueryStringParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
        url = window.location.href;
    }


    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&")
    var regex = new RegExp(`[?&]${name}(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)`),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';

    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a forward slash after `localhost:5000`

```
return getQueryStringParameterByName('useMockApi') ? 'http://localhost:5000/' : '/';
```

Comment: Thanks, actually figured that out myself, but thanks anyways